# PyQT4 how to using def from others model

Tags: python

This code works:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWebKit
from forma import Ui_MainWindow

class MyForm(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.pushButton,QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.strona)

    def strona(self):
        self.ui.webView.setUrl(QtCore.QUrl("http://plemiona.pl"))
```

but this

funkcje.py

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWebKit
from forma import Ui_MainWindow

def strona():
        self.ui.webView.setUrl(QtCore.QUrl("http://xxxx.pl"))



import sys, time, funkcje
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWebKit
from forma import Ui_MainWindow

class MyForm(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.pushButton,QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), funkcje.strona)
```

doesn't work...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\liczbapierwsza\TribalWarsBot\funkcje.py", line 5, in przejdz_na_strone_plemion
    QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
NameError: global name 'self' is not defined
```

how to import function from funkcje.py and use in e.x run.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`strona` needs to have access to the class instance, self. I'm not sure how you would go about passing the `self` parameter using Qt, but you can always write a wrapper function as part of your class that calls `strona` and passes the self parameter. Or import types and add `types.MethodType(funkcje.strona, self, MyForm)` to the class constructor(`__init__`). That adds funkcje.strona to the class. Note that the latter is untested by me.

**EDIT:** Here is what to do:

```
class MyForm(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        types.MethodType(strona, self, MyForm) 
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.pushButton,QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), strona)
```

Note: This is untested.

Comment: Can you post me the code you fixed? I have an idea what might be wrong, but I can't know for sure unless I can see what's going on.

Comment: hmm i cant... i dont know how fixed

Comment: @KozakPoprostu: I'm saying the code that you tried when you commented on this post.

Comment: @KozakPoprostu: Post it on a site like Pastebin(Google it) and give me the link. Also, there should be an edit button on the bottom of your question, above my answer.

Comment: @KozakPoprostu: I edited the post. Remember to import types first.